# Refugee travel to the UK

Tags: uk, paperwork, international-travel, legal, belgium

I have Convention 28 July 1951 issued to refugees by Belgium. I would like to travel to the UK.
I would like to know: do I need a visa to enter UK? Can I enter visa free? Or can I get a visa on arrival?

Comment: You can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y (scroll down the nationality list until you get to ‘Stateless and Refugee)

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply for a visa. The UK does not issue visas at the border, and people using 1951 convention travel documents are not eligible for visa free entry, since the UK suspended its participation in the European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees in 2003.